# Delete file in internal memory from Android device?

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to delete a file stored in internal memory. The file does gets deleted by using

```
activity.deleteFile(filename);
```

but only in emulator. On the actual device the method always returns false. When I try to access the file from adb shell there is permission denied being displayed. So, I guess there is permission related issue with deleting the files in internal memory.

Can someone let me know how to actually delete the file from internal memory in Android?

Comment: Did you create this file? What code did you use to create it? Are you able to read/access it at all on a device?

Comment: /data/data/packagename/files/filename.txt

Comment: The code to write the files is FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); fos.write(data.getBytes());

Comment: And yes, I am able to read the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about just any file in the file system... Does this not work?

```
if (new File("fileUrl").delete()) {
  // Deleted
} else {
  // Not deleted
}
```

Comment: Due to security constraints you can only access/modify/delete files that were created by your app. Otherwise code is ok, when accessing your own files.

Comment: @sunil The fileUrl would simply be the path of the file in question.

Comment: @PeterKnego Yeah, but it seems like it is a file created by his own app :)

Comment: Yes, the file is created by the same app from which I am trying to delete.

Comment: Okay. Then just create a new `File` with the full path of the file and call `delete()` on the `File` object. It's easy.

Comment: I even tried that but still cannot delete the file. I have checked file.exists and to my surprise even that returns false. But the data is written into the file.

Comment: My bad. I had done a very silly mistake. The file was not getting even created. Anyways thanks for helping out.

Comment: While this works, wouldn't it be better to use `activity.deleteFile(filename)` whenever you previously used `activity.openFileInput(filename)` to create the file (which automatically uses the Android internal data/files directory)?  Obviously we don't know how the @sunil created the files in this case, as it doesn't say, but noting this for future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

Due to [security constraints](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid) you can only delete files that were created by your app. You also can not delete files that are part of your app package (apk), i.e. files in `/res`, `/assets`, etc..

Comment: I am obviously trying to delete file which was created by the same app. I am not trying to delete a file which was created by another app.

Comment: Do you have path to that file? Then just do `(new File("path/to/file").delete())`

Comment: I am using File dir = context.getFilesDir(); File file = new File(dir, filename); file.delete();

Comment: Do you use `BufferedReader` to read the file? Or `BufferedWriter` to write it?

Comment: I use only fileoutputstream to write to files.

Answer (score 3):

Here FileName is the name of File which you want to delete and without path separator.that mean FileName should not contain path separator like "/".
And File should be created by your application.
My Problem was solved by that code..

`if(getApplicationContext().deleteFile(FileName))
 {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
else
 {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
_context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

when writing the file